# I am having trouble while running "npm install" command in CMD I have used several methods to fix this prob. but could not get away from this problem

Tags: node.js, npm

```
C:\Users\91931>npm install
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\91931\package-lock.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\91931\package-lock.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\91931\package-lock.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\91931\\package-lock.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91931\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-28T15_03_54_957Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Did you check _It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus), or that you lack permissions to access it._?

Comment: `C:\Users\91931\package-lock.json` hang on, did you initialize package on users folder? i am not sure if this is your project folder. even `-g` wouldnt install stuff there, it will go to `nodejs` installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command again in command prompt with administrator privileges.
On Windows, you can search for command prompt in the start menu -> right click Command Prompt (or select from the right panel in the start menu) -> Run as Administrator.

Also use cd to enter the directory where your Node.js application is stored. The directory should contain "package.json" and "package-lock.json". Then run "npm install" again. Administrator privileges are unlikely to be needed unless the directory is protected for some reason.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91931\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-28T15_50_07_634Z-debug-0.log

Comment: I am still facing this error. I've tried to run CMD as an administrator but couldn't get rid of this error.

Comment: Use cd to enter the directory with your node.js application environment. The directory should have a "package.json" file and perhaps a "package-lock.json" file as well. Use the command: cd "path/to/directory".
Then run "npm install" again.

Comment: It didn't work for this issue

Comment: @amykashyap stop, dont move. take a breather (you are touching system32). now, please open windows explorer. then navigate to your project folder, hold shift key, right click on the empty spot on the right pane. click "Open PowerShell Window here" (it might show "Open Command Prompt Window here" instead. see if the folder has `package.json` file. if yes, then carefully type in `npm install`.